# Vue data variable to methods and then to provide

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, apollo

I have issue to get some values from methods and want to parse to provide.
How I can solve the problem?

```
  methods: {
    onClickCategory: (value) => {
      return (this.catId = value);
    },
  },
  provide() {
    return {
      categoryId: this.value,
    };
  },
```

I get always categoryId:undefined

Answer (score 0):

As [Vue Guide highlights](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject),

> Note: the provide and inject bindings are NOT reactive. This is
> intentional. However, if you pass down an observed object, properties
> on that object do remain reactive.

So one solution is wrap your **value** into one observed object, like `test2.value` in below example:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.component('v-parent', {template: `
    <div>
      <h4>Example</h4>
      <p>Not Working: <input v-model="test1"></p>
      <p>Working: <input v-model="test2.value"></p>
      <v-child></v-child>
    </div>
`,
  data () {
    return {
      test1: 'blabla1',
      test2: {value: 'blabla2'}
    }
  },
  provide () {
    return {parent1: this.test1, parent2: this.test2}
  }
}),
Vue.component('v-child', {
  template: `<div><pre>{{parent1}}</pre><pre>{{parent2.value}}</pre></div>`,
  inject: ['parent1', 'parent2']
})
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <v-parent/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this is if I need to get from data, but I need to get from methods if someone click to pass value to provider.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

```
  methods: {
    onClickCategory(value) {
      this.categoryId.value = value;
    },
  },
  provide() {
    this.catID = this.categoryId;
    return {
      catId: this.catID,
    };
  },
```